# Request failed when adding sshex library

Tags: ssh, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to add [rubencaro's sshex](https://github.com/rubencaro/sshex) library to my project. But after running `mix deps.get` I get the following error:

```
Checking package (https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3-asia.hex.pm/tarballs/sshex-2.1.0.tar)
Request failed ({:failed_connect, [{:to_address, {'s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com', 443}}, {:inet, [:inet], :nxdomain}]})
** (Mix) Package fetch failed and no cached copy available
```

I guess it might be related to hex dependencies but I'm a newby on elixir and don't really know how to check that.

Comment: Looks like the mirror you have to retrieve hex packages does not have a copy of `sshex-2.1.0` and/or is temporary unavailable.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks @mudasobwa

Comment: Please consider answering your own question to close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey and welcome in the `elixir` community

I'm sorry that you already got stuck, but it is definitely not your fault. So keep your head and mood up - and enjoy Elixir.

I assume you have a working internet connection, and the mirror denies the access or does not have the file `mix` requests. In your mix config is `{:sshex, "~> 2.1"}` right?

I also assume you are from Asia? So try another mirror you can set the mirror like this in your command line prompt:

```
 $ HEX_MIRROR=https://repo.hex.pm mix deps.get
```

your can choose between Fastly: `https://repo.hex.pm` jsDelivr: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hex` and a private hosted version in China: `https://hex.elixir-cn.org` ... The Fastly is the official one.

I hope this resolves you problem!
Greetings from Austria

bMalum

Comment: thanks @bMalum, that worked great. I'm not in Asia, btw, I'm in Europe (Bulgaria at the moment). Happy to join the elixir community. Cheers!